# I cannot put each object side by side

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

With the reference to the subject, I cannot put each object which should be bracketed by the i tag. I would like to align it side by side. However I used a li tag and float:left and right on CSS, it was not changed. Does anyone know how to change the position?

```
 <section id="mypassion-section" class="bg-light text-muted py-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <img src="img/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px"  alt="" class="img-fluid mb-3 rounded-circle">
            <h3>生徒さんの成長</h3>
            <p>OOOOO様 <br>受講前</p>
            <i class="fa fa-play icon-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>受講後</p>
            <i class="fa fa-play icon-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
```

Comment: It is so unclear what exactly you want to achieve. Please be clear...

Answer (score 0):

Was there a reason you didn’t want to put the icons in the `p` tag?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="mypassion-section" class="bg-light text-muted py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=Logo" width="100px" height="100px" alt="" class="img-fluid mb-3 rounded-circle">
                <h3>生徒さんの成長</h3>
                <p>OOOOO様 <br>受講前</p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-play fa-rotate-180 icon-left" style="margin-right: 1rem;" aria-hidden="false"></i>
                受講後
                <i class="fa fa-play icon-right" style="margin-left: 1rem;" aria-hidden="false"></i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

It was good that you included some code in your question, but it's better to use the snippet tool to include things like the Bootstrap and Font Awesome CSS files and to provide a running example of what you have so far.

Comment: Thank you for showing the layout, but it is not exactly what I wanted to do...

Answer (score 0):

I used [bootstrap classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) to align items without changing much in DOM. Please check on the [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) to get more knowledge on Bootstrap Classes.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="mypassion-section" class="bg-light text-muted py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=Logo" width="100px" height="100px" alt="" class="img-fluid mb-3 rounded-circle">
                <h3>生徒さんの成長</h3>
                <p>OOOOO様 <br>受講前</p>
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <i class="fa fa-play fa-rotate-180 icon-left" style="margin-right: 1rem;" aria-hidden="false"></i>
                <p class="mb-0">受講後</p>
                <i class="fa fa-play icon-right" style="margin-left: 1rem;" aria-hidden="false"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```